# Deserializing XML, how do I access attributes?

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I have some XML that I am consuming and deserializing.

```
<Foo>
    <Bars Baz="9">
        <Bar>...</Bar>
        <Bar>...</Bar>
    </Bars>
</Foo>
```

Currently I deserialize it to this class:

```
[XmlRoot("Foo")]
public class Foo
{
    public Foo() { }

    [XmlArrayItem("Bar")]
    public Bar[] Bars { get; set; }
}
```

This works fine, except that I don't capture the value of `@Baz`.  I want to add `Baz` as a property of `Foo`, but I'm not sure how.  What attribute would I set on my `Baz` property to properly deserialize the xml?

```
[WhatAttributeGoesHere("?")]
public int Baz { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Normally:

```
[XmlAttribute]
```

(with optional name,  namespace, etc) is what you are after.

However, you can't use that directly on a collection. You would need instead to have a wrapper class for Bars, with the attribute and a:

```
public class Foo {
    public BarWrapper Bars {get;set;}
}
public class BarWrapper {
    private readonly List<Bar> bars = new List<Bar>();
    [XmlElement("Bar")]
    public List<Bar> Items {get{return bars;}}

    [XmlAttribute]
    public int Baz {get;set;}
}
public class Bar {...}
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to avoid.  Is there a way to access the attribute without creating a sub class?

Comment: @gilly3 with XmlSerializer? Only by implementing IXmlSerializable; and given the choice, I'd choose an extra layer in my DTO :)

Comment: Ya, I'm not going there! I guess I'll have to suck it up and add the extra layer.

Comment: @gilly3 if you don't want to impact existing code, you can always add pass-thru properties marked [XmlIgnore]?