# How can XML Deserializer be configured to pick up an attribute?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, xml-deserialization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Deserializing XML, how do I access attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003847/deserializing-xml-how-do-i-access-attributes)

I am deserializing the following XML:

```
<root>
  <foo> some content </foo>
  <bar id="someId">someContent</bar>
</root>
```

Into a Class object below using `XMLSerializer`.

```
[XmlRootAttribute("foobar")]
public class foobar
{

    [XmlElementAttribute("foo")]
    public string foo { get; set; }

    [XmlElementAttribute("bar")]
    public string bar { get; set; }        

}
```

However, this does not pick up `someId` within the `bar` tag. What change do I need to make to pick it up as well?

I tried this:

In the class above, I changed the second property to:

```
[XmlElementAttribute("bar")]
public Bar bar { get; set; }
```

And then defined a new class:

```
[XmlTypeAttribute]
    public class Bar
    {
        [XmlAttribute("id")]
        public string id { get; set; }

        [XmlText]
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

This still picks up the value but not the `Id`.

Comment: I think you have to make your 'bar' object something else than a string, because having an attribute doesn't make sense for a string.

Comment: have you tried XmlAttribute without ("id") ?

Comment: Same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003847/deserializing-xml-how-do-i-access-attributes

Comment: @Steve:I just did. It still won't pick it up

Comment: @Steve: Changing it to `XmlAttribute` did fix it. The reason I didn't realize it immediately was because of another bug in my code. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use XmlAttribute without ("id") that should fix it.